# Как правильно указать сравнение в коде?

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите в чем ошибка? Если что? до этого в функции была уже объявлена переменная gr.

```
if ( let gr == "Мир") {
            alert ("true");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор `if` занимается тем, что проверяет условие в скобках, никаких объявлений новых переменных там быть не может (вы в коде даже попытались объявить переменную и сразу сравнить, так тоже делать нельзя)

```
 if (gr === "Мир") {
   alert ("true");
 }
```

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы мое условие выполнялось и именно после него уже шел then

Comment: сделай через промисы

Comment: @AndreyFreiz, прости за такой вопрос, но что это?) Я просто еще новичок во всем этом

Comment: @АлинаСотская, обновил ответ

Comment: @АлинаСотская https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise